# Is there a way to bubble up a ref for a nested component rendered by a function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React JS and Stripe JS to render a reusable payment form.

This is working fine except for one case which requires a button to be rendered outside of the component.

I was hoping to use a ref for the custom payment form but, because of the way Stripe requires the component to be injected and wrapped with an ElementsConsumer component, the underlying component class that is rendered isn't accessible so the 'ref' property cannot be used.

In the below example, would there be a way for me to allow a ref to be used for the '_PaymentForm' class when the 'PaymentForm' function is used to render it?

Thanks!

```
class _PaymentForm extends React.Component<PaymentFormProps, PaymentFormState>  {
    ...
}

const InjectedPaymentForm = (props: PaymentFormProps) => {
    return (
        <ElementsConsumer>
            {({ elements, stripe }) => (
                <_PaymentForm {...props} elements={elements} stripe={stripe} />
            )}
        </ElementsConsumer>
    );
}

export const PaymentForm = (props: PaymentFormProps) => {
    const stripePromise = loadStripe(props.stripeApiKey);

    return (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
            <InjectedPaymentForm {...props} />
        </Elements>
    );
}

export default PaymentForm;
```

Comment: You should be able to define the ref inside `PaymentForm` then pass it as a prop into the `InjectedPaymentForm` - have you tried this?

Comment: @Luke - I'm not sure how I would do that, sorry. Could you please give an example?

Comment: Can you clarify what you need the ref for? Looking at the stripe docs, I'm not seeing a good use case for the ref. Which element are you trying to access via ref and what functionality are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Just to expose a function in the underlying component, not one of the Stripe components - it just happens to be a component that needs to have the Stripe element wrappers.

Comment: can you update the code example to show the function you want to expose and where you want to call that function from?